# Viewing pseudo node and dangle nodes using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

We know that we require production mapping extension and ARCINFO license to view the pseude node and dangle nodes.We have to see these nodes without these functionality through python scripting,but I do not have to use any in-built tool ,I have to make my own tool through python which can helps me viewing the nodes

Comment: Are you looking to do topology using arcpy? If so, you can start [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Create_Topology/0017000000nr000000/).

Comment: If you are not bound to python scripting, you could use QGIS with the "Topology Checker" plugin. If yes, ignore this comment :)

Comment: Production Mapping is not required for geodatabase topology but a Standard (ArcEditor) or Advanced (ArcInfo) is. If you don't have acess to those levels, there are some third-party add-ons, such as [ET GeoTools](http://www.ian-ko.com/) that are bit more cost effective and contain similar tools/function. See also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133928/ and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17743/ that have some other Basic (ArcView) methods.

Answer (score 4):

The tool  [arcpy.FeatureVerticesToPoints_management](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003p000000) has an option to write dangle nodes, or ALL vertices.

Another tool you can look at is [arcpy.ExportTopologyErrors_management](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Export_Topology_Errors/00170000015w000000/) which will export all topology errors to standalone feature classes. You'll need to create a topology and define it's rules first though.

Comment: Feature Vertices to Points, and therefore I assume the arcpy calling of it, also requires an Advanced/Info license which asker says they don't have.